# Android spinner show different items in pop-up from a string array

Tags: android, arraylist, spinner, android-spinner

My spinner allows users to select countries. I want the selected item to have
only the country code as seen in the first picture and when user selects the dropdown the pop=up to have more information like in picture 2

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

This is what i have tried so far

```
Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinnerCountries);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterCountry = new ArrayAdapter<> ( this, R.layout.spinner3_list, CountryData.countryAreaCodes);
        dataAdapterCountry.setDropDownViewResource ( R.layout.spinner3_dropdown_items );
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapterCountry);
```

My data comes from an array in a different class CountryData seen below (shortened).

```
class CountryData {
    public static final String[] countryAreaCodes = {"+960","+223"..."};
    public static final String[] countryNamesFull = {"Maldives +254","Mali +223"...};
   }
```

I read [this](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/12/custom-spinner-with-icon.html) but never quite got it coz i am using arrays. And i dont want to use libraries too!!

Comment: You want to hide the image in the spinner? can you please share the layout of spinner's item you're using?

Comment: @HamzaAbbas not really. I want the dropdown popup list to have more data than the selected item

Comment: you want the list to show the items at all times? why don't you just use a list?

Comment: Spinners have 2 modes  android:spinnerMode="dialog" should do what you're trying to show in picture 2.